# Faster user switch in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac

Does anyone know a way to switch between two users faster than the current method?
this rotating cube is a waste of time.

Comment: You must be a developer :)

Comment: Having to unsleep and then 'switch user' is the worst. Steve Jobs should fix that up before embarking on any cloudscapes. Bizarrely, logging on as one user and then switching appears to be faster than switching directly. I've found by doing that it can take only 30-60 seconds rather than well over a minute using this technique. Also, is there a shortcut key for 'switch user'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to disable the rotating cube effect by changing the resolution or color depth in one of the accounts. Unfortunately, it does not make the switch go any faster. Instead of the cube eye-candy, it fades to blue while it readjusts the resolution.

Comment: The cube animation is cute the first few times you use it, but starts to get in the way when you use it heavily. Would you like your browser to perform a little animation every time you clicked on another tab?

Comment: How often do you change accounts?
I thought I was impatient ;-)

Comment: As a freelancer with several different clients, I find it convenient to set up a different user account for each client. Each account has its own set email addresses, contacts, bookmarks, etc. I sometimes flip through the accounts in rapid succession to check for new emails, instant messages, or whatever. (I do have a master account that I can check with a single interface, but it doesn't always pick up on cross-chatter among other people in a group.)

Answer (score 4):

Do you need the Mac OS X GUI? If not, there is always 'su' via Terminal.app.